# Porque no me funciona la clase , Class 'Image' not found?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

```
use Image;



    $empresa= empresa::find($id);
   $empresa->fill($request->all());

    if ($request->hasFile('logo')) 

      {
     $imagen=$request->file('logo');

      $image_name = time(). '.'. $imagen->getClientOriginalName();
      $destination_path= public_path()."/image_empresas";
     Image::make('logo')->save($destination_path, $image_name);

     $empresa->logo = $image_name;
   Storage::delete($image_name);
    }

    $empresa->save();
```

el codigo me funciona si no utilizo el

```
  Image::make('logo')->save($destination_path, $image_name);
```

Comment: ¿Añadiste el `service providers` y el alias?

Comment: este es el alias    'Image' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Image::class, pero el service providers no me sale

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente la clase/librería que estas instalando?

Comment: intervention/image pero aun no me funciona

Comment: Creo que simplemente te falta la extension en `make('logo')`, cambialo por algo asi: `make('logo.png')`

Answer (score 1):

Los pasos correctos para usar la libreria serian:

**1. Posicionado en la raiz de tu proyecto ejecutar:**

```
composer require intervention/image
```

**2. En el archivo /config/app.php dentro de la seccion providers agregar al final:**

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
```

**3. En el archivo /config/app.php dentro de la seccion aliases agregar al final:**

```
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
```

Luego de estos pasos deberia funcionar sin problemas

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funcionó de esta forma:

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
```

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Gracias por intentar ayudar a resolver la pregunta. ¿Dónde y cómo debería usar esto quien pregunta? Trata de explicar siempre (brevemente al menos) el cómo y el porqué